# Latex Beamer: Adjust template to display dots per subsection- not page

Tags: beamer, header-footer, presentations

I really want to use this beamer template: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ytu-beamer-theme/ntqbsbgpcwjz

Using this, results in the following header

[image]

So, using this template gives me a header entry for each section and dots below for each page. As soon as the page is shown, the corresponding dot is highlighted. However, my presentation is quite big which results in many many dots. Is there a way to customize this template to one of these options:

- Add dots only for subsections and not per page (preferred)
- Delete dots

Thanks!